# Feeds doesn't import photos

Tags: commerce, feeds

I imported products with the help of **feeds** via **[commerce product processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds)**. All products data downloaded correctly except the product photo.

It downloaded from csv file, where there is a full direct path to the picture. At settings of acceptability to this field : `photo: URI (field_product_photo:uri)`

Import runs without mistakes, but there is no product photo in a product's description. Which is strange because the file is copied to `sites/default/files/` it's saving the origin name, except saving in `sites/default/files/images` and changing the origin name to **sku** , as it should be by making this products list by hand-labour.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I need more information about the error. Is the photo being copied into sites/default/files (regardless of where the actual file is going, just want to make sure its actually being copied)? Give me an example path of where the file starts, where it ends up, and where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Thans for your reply. We've already solved the problem. It was bug in sql in file_managed. The total truncate of the table helped.

Comment: goldlord - You're welcome! You can upvote comments that are helpful by hovering to the left of comments and clicking the up arrow that appears. It's a nice way to say thanks for those of us in the community. :)